# c# quartz update ui

Tags: c#, wpf, quartz-scheduler

I create a little app. I create observable colletion of string and job(in quartz) every 5 second i add new item in my collection, but ui doesnt update. please help

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
     public ObservableCollection<string> Products { get; set; }
     //my logic.....
     public void UpdateCol()
     {
        Products.Add("2");
     }
} 
public class Test:IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //How call method from UpdateCol from MainWindow????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first call `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` on your collection after creating it so that it can be safely updated from background thread (This solution is .NET 4.5+ only):

```
private object lock_ = new object();
public MainWindow()
{
   Products = new ObservableCollection<string>();
   BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Products, lock_);
}
```

On older .NET, you have to use `Dispatcher` objected to do the work for you like this:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    window.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(window.UpdateCol));
}
```

Comment: Execute call in another class(Test) if i create window i get exeption about thread sta